# 3d stl vector memory size issue

Tags: c++

```
 std::vector< std::vector< std::vector<int> > > sp(1, std::vector< std::vector<int> >(1,std::vector<int>(1)));
```

What should be the memory allocated for this 3d vector?
Massif shows 84 bytes, but shouldn't it be close to the size of int(4 bytes) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally a single `std::vector` is implemented using 3 pointers

- a pointer to the begin of the allocated area
- a pointer to the end of valid data
- a pointer to the end of the allocated area (reserved space)

thus on a 64-bit platform it's at least 3x8 = 24 bytes in addition to actual content, of course.

A 3d vector with one integer therefore would occupy at least 24x3 + sizeof(int) = 76 bytes supposing integers are 4 bytes. With 8-bytes integer would be 80 bytes, not counting any extra alignment needed for example by the heap allocator.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this seems like a overhead. So if i do 
    std::vector< std::vector< std::vector<int> > > sp(1, std::vector< std::vector<int> >(1,std::vector<int>(2)));
This should take up only one extra int right? but it took 12 more bytes, 96 bytes now, and if i change it to 3 plus 12 more bytes 108. why is that?

Comment: `std::vector` typically allocates a memory block that is larger than what it immediately needs. This is to avoid too many re-allocations as it grows. See the difference between `std::vector::capacity` and `std::vector::size`.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but thats the first thing i did, the capacity is 1 , 1 and 2 as expected

Answer (score 4):

When you use STL you have to consider that your data structures are not only composed by the data itself but the meta-data. They are objects not memory regions.

For each vector object, you have several attributes. Look at:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Answer (score 1):

By hand calculus it seems that each vector holds 7 elements at start. Thus `7*sizeof(int)*3 = 84`

Answer (score 1):

Why should it  be close to 4 bytes? std::vector is a class with more than just the element attribute! If you are short on memory you should probably not use std::vector and simply use an array or your own implementation of an ArrayList that is closer to the standard array size!